# Show me comment flags in-line like deleted comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, flags, moderator-tools

Currently when viewing a flagged post, comment flags are displayed much like regular flags: at the bottom in a special 'window'.

When a handful of comments on the same post are flagged, especially for different reasons, especially when understanding the flag requires looking at deleted comments (I'm looking at you, *obsolete*), it can be annoying to handle the flag.

Please either replace the above with or add the additional functionality of: showing the comment flag in-line, that is, right next to the flagged comment. You can highlight it yellow, write the word *obsolete* (eg.) next to the vote button, or put a little unicorn next to it. Just something so when I show up, I can hit "deleted comments" on the left and immediately identify the flagged comments *in situ* (and ideally why they are flagged) without having to read through a whole conversation to get context. This would make handling those flags easier, IMO.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233711/162102, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233610/162102.